# Thread failed to start C# due to low virtual memory condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, threadpool

Today one my client received an error (below) while running my application

> *ERR::-2146233051: Thread failed to start.    at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at System.Threading.Thread.Start()*

=========

As you can see it states that failed to create the thread. The code used for creating Thread

```
//-state -> stateobject for receving socketdata

objState.m_strReceivedData = state.m_strReceivedData;
objState.m_strComputerName = state.m_strComputerName;

objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MethodName));
                            objThread.Start(objState);
```

Based upon the error it seems that error has occurred in the above code. Also, in event viewer, there were warning for low memory stating my exe was using the most virtual memory. Below is the message I got in event viewer.

> *Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: application.exe
>   (4272) consumed 32793702400*

I think there is memory leak going on, so should I forcefully call GC.Collect() 
Or is there any other option to..?

Please advice! Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: Calling GC is not good and standard choice. Use memory profiler like "MemProfiler" to detect memory leaks.

Comment: To add on @MojtabaTajik comment, the GC is smart enough to automatically trigger when the system is low on memory. So forcing a call in that situation won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Follow below for less memory consumption:

1.When ever if object created and used and you don't need it further make it null.

2.Don't keep unnecessary data loaded/Don't try to load huge data at a time

like 
      1.) huge data read from files
      2.) huge data read from Data base

3.when ever you don't use the object in a block don't mention it in a block,so it is easy for GC to Collect it fastly.

4.Don't contain copy of same data objects for example

```
  public class Student
    {
       string Name;
       string ID;
    }
```

if there are two objects created for this with same data

Student1 {
              Name: ramu,
              ID:40
            }

and you created another object student2 having same data then

Stuent2 {
   Name: ramu,
               ID:40
            }

Now even if it is different object but it is duplication of data

Which off course occupies memory

```
if student1=2mb
then student2=2mb
total 4mb for maintaining same data
```